# How can i resolve ExecucuteNonQuery throwing exception Incorrect syntex near '?'

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Dim StrSql = "update student set id=?"

Updated (StrSql,15)

Public Function Updated (ByVal strSql As String, ByVal ParamArray Parameters As String ())
    For Each x In Parameters
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?",x)
    Next

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Function
```

Comment: Try `@Id` for your parameter name like `... set id=@Id`. Also is your id an integer or a varchar in your database?

Comment: First things first, please spend time in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question. A title and some code is never a proper question. The question itself must contain a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem and the title should summarise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't leave us much to go on; as jmcilhinney points out, you need to add more detail to future questions. For example in this one you have code there that doesn't compile at all, doesnt mention the types of any variable, you don't give the name of the database...

...I'm fairly sure that "Incorrect syntax near" is a SQL Server thing, in which case you need to remember that it (re)uses named parameters, unlike e.g. Access which uses positional ones:

```
SQL Server:
strSql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE firstname = @name OR lastname = @name"
...Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Lee")

Access:
strSql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE firstname = ? OR lastname = ?"
...Parameters.AddWithValue("anythingdoesntmatterwillbeignored", "Lee")
...Parameters.AddWithValue("anythingdoesntmatterwillbeignoredalso", "Lee")
```

This does mean your function will need to get a bit more intelligent; perhaps pass a ParamArray of KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)

Or perhaps you should stop doing this way right now, and switch to using Dapper. Dapper takes your query, applies your parameters and returns you objects if you ask for them:

```
Using connection as New SqlConnection(...)

  Dim p as List(Of Person) = Await connection.QueryAsync(Of Person)( _
    "SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = @name", _
    New With { .name = "John" } _
  )

  ' use your list of Person objects

End Using
```

Yep, all that adding parameters BS, and executing the reader, and converting the results to a Person.. Dapper does it all. Nonquery are done like `connection.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE person SET name=@n, age=@a WHERE id=@id", New With{ .n="john", .a=27, .id=123 })`

http://dapper-tutorial.net

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

```
Updated(StrSql, 15)
```

Your Updated Function calls for a String array. `15` is not a string array.

Functions need a datatype for the return.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", X)
```

`cmd` is not declared.

You can't possible get the error you mention with the above code. It will not even compile, let alone run and produce an error.

It is not very helpful to write a Function that is trying to be generic but is actually very limited.

Let us start with your Update statement.

```
Dim StrSql = "update student set id=?"
```

The statement you provided will update every id in the student table to 15. Is that what you intended to do? ID fields are rarely changed. They are meant to uniquely identify a record. Often, they are auto-number fields. An Update command would use an ID field to identify which record to update.

Don't use `.AddWithValue`. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Since you didn't tell us what database you are using I guessed it was Access because of the question mark. If it is another database change the connection, command and dbType types.

Using...End Using block ensures you connection and command are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your Connection String"

Public Function Updated(StudentNickname As String, StudentID As Integer) As Integer
    Dim RetVal As Integer
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update student set NickName = @NickName Where StudentID = @ID", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NickName", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = StudentNickname
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = StudentID
        cn.Open()
        RetVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    Return RetVal
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim RowsUpdated = Updated("Jim", 15)
    Dim message As String
    If RowsUpdated = 1 Then
        message = "Success"
    Else
        message = "Failure"
    End If
    MessageBox.Show(message)
End Sub
```

This code keeps your database code separated from user interface code.

Comment: Re the `For Each X In Parameters`, with `Option Infer On` that statement itself will declare `X` and give it the correct type based on `Parameters` (unless `Parameters` doesn't have a typed `Current` in which case it will be `Object`).

Comment: @Craig Yes, I didn't read the error closely enough. It was referring to an Imports I had with a conflict. renamed the parameter from x to p and all was well. Will edit that out of my answer.